# How to reusing class constructor argument as literal string with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, constructor

How I can do this?

```js
type Module = {
    created: number;
}

class Example {
    constructor(
        public readonly moduleName: string
    ) { }

    getModule = (modules: {
        [this.moduleName]: Module // <-- property error
    }) => modules[this.moduleName]
}
```

property error is "A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type."

The playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwK4BtoF4oG8CwAoKQqAYwCcIBDYCBALigDskBbAIwlIG58BfffYigoBnYVAAqEYcGz4iJOA2mkkxYHFIAKOfKJgkrFAEtiUchQSKUIKM0SoIAOQrMI9ZUYYBzHYQCU2FB8eL5QXhDA8MhoUJiadtFS9LgEuoQA2sAAFkbCAHQJDs6uALr0UQ6hPAHoAHy29mjCmTn5hWjFECW8QA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are tryna do?

```
type Module = {
    created: number;
}

class Test<T extends string> {
    constructor(
        public readonly moduleName: T
    ) { }

    getModule = (modules: {
        [key: string]: Module
    }): Module => modules[this.moduleName]
}
```

You are trying to mix static typing with dynamic assembly at run-time. Without giving the type system information about possible values, like `ModuleNames` as a string literal discriminated union, there little it can tell you about what this is doing at run-time.

It looks like this object will take a keyed object of modules, and return from that "its own module".

Like this:

```
type Module = {
    created: number;
}

interface ModuleCache { [key: string]: Module }

class Test<T extends string> {
    constructor(
        public readonly moduleName: T
    ) { }

    getModule = (modules: ModuleCache): Module =>
        modules[this.moduleName]
}
```